# "Farther off something"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> He took them in at a swift glance. No use. No one he knew, except—he
>   responded to the greeting listlessly—a gentleman to whom he had spoken
>   on the train, and ***farther off*** ***a familiar face*** from the
>   metropolis. (The Burning Secret, Stefan Zweig)

What does the marked phrase above mean?

Comment: It is two phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Farther" is a comparative form of "far" ([see the OED](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/far)).

The phrase "farther off" means "further away": that is, more distant.

A "familiar face" (see meaning 4 in [the Oxford Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/face_1)) is simply a face which is familiar; here it's being used to mean a person whom the character recognises.

So the phrase
"No one he knew, except a gentleman, and farther off, a familiar face."
means he knew two people: one was a gentleman to whom he had spoken on the train, and one was someone he recognised who was more distant in space.

Comment: Thank you. This construction seemed a little strange to me. Could I rewrite that sentence as in: "No use. No one he knew, except—he responded to the greeting listlessly—a gentleman to whom he had spoken on the train, and a familiar face from the metropolis farther off." or  "... and a familiar face farther off from the metropolis."

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Both are fine, but I think the latter is better. "… from the metropolis farther off" has a slight risk of being misinterpreted as "… from the metropolis which is farther off".